# WinDbg analyze "Not Responding" App

Tags: windbg

1. I have two application that hang/Not Responding on Ctrl+Shift+0 press.
2. Ctrl+Shift+0 change language from current to russian
3. App is Visual Studio 2015 and Skype 7.18.85 [Skype support](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Win10-7-5-0-102-crashes-after-changing-language-via-Alt-Shift-2/m-p/4006211/highlight/true#M349781)
4. I`m not hacker
5. I install WDK, WinDbg, ProcessExplorer
6. VS and skype has many thread an all thread not hang
7. I think Ctr+Shift+0 run same process/thread that work in cycle and lock GUI

There easy way detect what lock GUI

Comment: Not responding means that the UI thread is not pumping messages. I.e. it is busy. Look at what it is doing.

Comment: ~0s show wow64win!NtUserMessageCall+0x14: